# Scapy - распарсить radiotap

Tags: python, wifi, radio, scapy

```
>>> from scapy.layers.dot11 import RadioTap
>>> r=RadioTap(b'\x00\x00\x18\x00.@\x00\xa0 \x08\x00\x00\x00\x02l\t\xa0\x00\xbd\x00\x00\x00\xbd\x00H\x11:\x01h\x15\x90\xe7\x99\x10\x80\x01\x84@BWh\x15\x90\xe7\x99\x10\xc0l')
<RadioTap  version=0 pad=0 len=24 present=Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+b14+b29+Ext notdecoded=' \x08\x00\x00\x00\x02l\t\xa0\x00\xbd\x00\x00\x00\xbd\x00' |<Dot11  subtype=4 type=Data proto=0 FCfield=to-DS+pw-mgt ID=14849 addr1=68:15:90:e7:99:10 addr2=80:01:84:40:42:57 addr3=68:15:90:e7:99:10 SC=27840 |>>
>>> r.fields
{'version': 0, 'pad': 0, 'len': 24, 'present': <Flag 2684370990 (Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+b14+b29+Ext)>, 'notdecoded': b' \x08\x00\x00\x00\x02l\t\xa0\x00\xbd\x00\x00\x00\xbd\x00'}
```

Как получить dBm_AntSignal, Channel? В Scapy нет парсера или что-то не настроил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В версии на pypi функционала нет. В мастере есть.